# How do I get my logarithm and ln in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, calculator, logarithm, ln

I built a calculator with Kotlin, but I have a problem when I want to logarithm and get ln

I get the following error when I run my program and want to get my logarithm

invalid Double :

this my code

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResult"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:maxLines="1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvExpress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:maxLines="1"/>


<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="7"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvClear"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="AC" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvBackspace"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="C" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOpen"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="(" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvClose"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text=")" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSinus"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="Sin" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCosine"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="Cos" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTangent"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="Tan" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLog"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="Log" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLn"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="ln" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSquared"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="x!" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSquare"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="x²" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRadical"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="√" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvInv"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="1/x" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDivide"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="÷" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSeven"
                style="@style/ButtonNumber"
                android:text="7" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEight"
                style="@style/ButtonNumber"
                android:text="8" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNine"
                style="@style/ButtonNumber"
                android:text="9" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMul"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="*" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFour"
                style="@style/ButtonNumber"
                android:text="4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFive"
                style="@style/ButtonNumber"
                android:text="5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSix"
                style="@style/ButtonNumber"
                android:text="6" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMinus"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="-" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOne"
                style="@style/ButtonNumber"
                android:text="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTwo"
                style="@style/ButtonNumber"
                android:text="2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvThree"
                style="@style/ButtonNumber"
                android:text="3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPlus"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="+" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvP"
                style="@style/ButtonNumber"
                android:text="π" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvZero"
                style="@style/ButtonNumber"
                android:text="0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDot"
                style="@style/ButtonNumber"
                android:text="." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEquals"
                style="@style/ButtonConverter"
                android:text="=" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

and

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    //numbers
    tvZero.setOnClickListener { appOnExpression("0" , true) }
    tvOne.setOnClickListener { appOnExpression("1" , true) }
    tvTwo.setOnClickListener { appOnExpression("2" , true) }
    tvThree.setOnClickListener { appOnExpression("3" , true) }
    tvFour.setOnClickListener { appOnExpression("4" , true) }
    tvFive.setOnClickListener { appOnExpression("5" , true) }
    tvSix.setOnClickListener { appOnExpression("6" , true) }
    tvSeven.setOnClickListener { appOnExpression("7" , true) }
    tvEight.setOnClickListener { appOnExpression("8" , true) }
    tvNine.setOnClickListener { appOnExpression("9" , true) }
    tvDot.setOnClickListener { appOnExpression("." , true) }

    //unit converter
    tvPlus.setOnClickListener { appOnExpression("+" , false) }
    tvMinus.setOnClickListener { appOnExpression("-" , false) }
    tvMul.setOnClickListener { appOnExpression("*" , false) }
    tvDivide.setOnClickListener { appOnExpression("/" , false) }
    tvP.setOnClickListener { appOnExpression("π" , false) }

    tvP.setOnClickListener {
        if (tvExpress.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            tvExpress.text = tvExpress.text.toString()+3.14
        }else {
            tvExpress.text = "3.14"
        }
    }

    tvSinus.setOnClickListener {
        tvExpress.text = tvExpress.text.toString()+"sin"
    }

    tvCosine.setOnClickListener {
        tvExpress.text = tvExpress.text.toString()+"cos"
    }

    tvTangent.setOnClickListener {
        tvExpress.text = tvExpress.text.toString()+"tan"
    }

    tvLog.setOnClickListener {
        tvExpress.text = tvExpress.text.toString()+"log"
    }

    tvLn.setOnClickListener {
        tvExpress.text = "ln"
    }

    tvInv.setOnClickListener {
        tvExpress.text = tvExpress.text.toString()+"^"+"(-1)"
    }

    tvSquare.setOnClickListener {
        if (tvExpress.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext , "عدد مورد نظر را وارد کنید" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else {
            val d = tvExpress.text.toString().toLong()
            val square = d * d
            tvExpress.text = square.toString()
            tvResult.text = "$d²"
        }
    }

    tvSquared.setOnClickListener {
        if (tvExpress.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext , "لطفا عدد مورد نظر خود را وارد کنید" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else {
            fun factorial(n: Int) : Int {
                return if (n == 0 || n == 1) 1 else n * factorial(n - 1)
            }
            val value : Int = tvExpress.text.toString().toInt()
            val fact : Int = factorial(value)
            tvExpress.text = fact.toString()
            tvResult.text = "$value'!"
        }
    }

    tvRadical.setOnClickListener {
        if (tvExpress.text.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext , "عدد مورد نظر را وارد کنید" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else {
            val str = tvExpress.text.toString()
            val r = sqrt(str.toDouble())
            val unit = r.toLong()
            val result = unit.toString()
            tvExpress.text = result
        }
    }

    tvBackspace.setOnClickListener {
        val strNumber = tvExpress.text.toString()
        if (strNumber.isNotEmpty()) {
            tvExpress.text = strNumber.substring(0, strNumber.length - 1)
        }
    }

    tvClear.setOnClickListener {
        tvResult.text = ""
        tvExpress.text = ""
    }

    tvEquals.setOnClickListener {
        val express = ExpressionBuilder(tvExpress.text.toString()).build()
        val result = express.evaluate()
        val longResult = result.toLong()
        if (result == longResult.toDouble()) {
            try {
                tvExpress.text = longResult.toString()
            }catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("check" , e.message.toString())
            }
        }else {
            tvExpress.text = result.toString()
        }
    }
}
private fun appOnExpression(str: String , bool: Boolean) {
    if (tvResult.text.isNotEmpty()) {
        tvExpress.text = ""
    }
    if (bool) {
        tvResult.text = ""
        tvExpress.append(str)
    }else {
        tvExpress.append(tvResult.text)
        tvExpress.append(str)
        tvResult.text = ""
    }
}
```

}

I used this library

```
dependencies {
implementation 'net.objecthunter:exp4j:0.4.8'  
}
```

How can I define a value so that logarithm and ln are received in my calculator and I can get the value I enter in the calculator?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're doing, but I can tell you any time you use `==` with Floats or Doubles, it's a mistake because it is almost impossible to be true unless the two compared values were calculated in the exact same way from the same constants.

Comment: Where did you want to use them?  there's no way to tell from your code.  I'm assuming its in the ExpressionBuilder, but we have no way of knowing what that is-  that's not a java or kotlin standard class, its some random library you're using.

Comment: The error message in your logcat should tell you exactly which line is causing the problem, but like @GabeSechan says, we can't see how the string is being turned into a double. Also you're not appending "ln" to a value, you're replacing it. And your ``tvSquare`` click listener is performing the calculation directly on the text by calling ``toLong`` on it, and that's gonna crash if you've added any non-numeric characters to it (which all the other buttons do)